# An analytical expression to calculate the stress triaxiality for a single notch sample

Tags: stresses

As far as I know, there is a formula (Bridgman) for the calculation of stress triaxiality for a sample having a notch on either side or for a flat grooved sample.

Now my question is, if I have a sample just having a single notch on one side can I use the Bridgman formula?

[image]

Comment: There are analytical expressions.  See https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/4385492.pdf, Section 6.1.1.3.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee So many thanks for your attention and response, but in Fig.6.1, it was shown that the shape of the sample is in the flat-grooved plate. And both sides of the sample have a notch, while my sample has just one notch.

Comment: You will need to go to the cited literature to find your case.  It exists, as far as I know.  However, I'm not affiliated with a university and don't have access to scientific journal literature.

Comment: I looked at the reference, but it was not what I have searched for. Thnx